# How to unite 2 subqueries to reduce retrieving data from cumbersome tables?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.1, query-performance

There are 3 tables: `user`, `conversation`, `message`.

Table `user`:

- id,
- login,
- last_login_time (time of last user's login),
- ...

Table `conversation`:

- id,
- user1_id,
- user2_id,
- message_last_read_id_user1 - id of last read message by user user1_id,
- message_last_write_id_user1 - id of last written message by user user1_id,
- message_last_read_id_user2 - id of last read message by user user2_id
- message_last_write_id_user2 - id  of last written message by user user2_id,
- ...

Table `message`:

- id,
- conversation_id,
- poster_id - user's id, who send that message,
- msg,
- ...

The aim to select users who logged during the last hour and select for each of them amount of unread messages:

```
SELECT u.id, u.login, u.last_login_time, 
( 
  SELECT count ( * ) FROM conversation c, message m 
  WHERE c.user1_id = u.id AND m.conversation_id = c.id AND
        COALESCE(c.message_last_read_id_user1, 0) < COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user2, 0) AND 
        m.id > COALESCE(message_last_read_id_user1, 0) AND m.id <= COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user2, 0) AND 
        m.poster_id = c.user2_id
) AS unread_user1, 
( 
  SELECT count ( * ) FROM conversation c, message m 
  WHERE user2_id = u.id AND m.conversation_id = c.id AND 
        COALESCE(message_last_read_id_user2, 0) < COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user1, 0) AND 
    c.user1_id > 0 AND m.id > COALESCE(message_last_read_id_user2, 0) AND m.id <= COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user1, 0) AND 
        m.poster_id != c.user2_id 
) AS unread_user2
FROM user u WHERE u.last_login_time >= 1452504418;
```

One of unread_user1 or unread_user2 always will be 0.
Query plan is here http://explain.depesz.com/s/VT6

In that query two subqueries have cross join `conversation c, message m` and it's very heavy operation. So maybe someone have idea how to unite these subqueries into one?

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to count using an expression:

```
SELECT u.id, u.login, u.last_login_time
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(c.message_last_read_id_user1, 0) 
                     < COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user2, 0) 
                   AND m.id > COALESCE(message_last_read_id_user1, 0) 
                   AND m.id <= COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user2, 0) 
                   AND m.poster_id = c.user2_id
                  THEN 1
             END) as unread_user1
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN COALESCE(message_last_read_id_user2, 0) 
                     < COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user1, 0) 
                   AND c.user1_id > 0 
                   AND m.id > COALESCE(message_last_read_id_user2, 0) 
                   AND m.id <= COALESCE(message_last_write_id_user1, 0) 
                   AND m.poster_id <> c.user2_id
                  THEN 1
             END) as unread_user2   
FROM user u 
JOIN conversation c
    ON c.user1_id = u.id
JOIN message m
    ON m.conversation_id = c.id
WHERE u.last_login_time >= 1452504418
GROUP BY u.id, u.login, u.last_login_time;
```

I might have missed some parts when rewriting, but hopefully you will get some ideas.

Comment: I tried your method but it's slower than mine.

Comment: Have you compared the plans and seen where each cost originates from?

Comment: Problem with `message` table join, I have simplified your query http://pastebin.com/80Vzb9za and made explain analyze http://explain.depesz.com/s/2B0. Index scan `conversation_pkey` with condition `id = m.conversation_id,` tooks most time. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Oh, I have postgresql 9.1 and I don't have LATERAL JOIN.

Comment: I removed that one. Always a good idea to tag your question with the correct version, at least I assume current version unless tagged otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If newer messages consistently have larger ID values in the `message` table than the older messages, perhaps you could simplify the filter conditions in your subqueries by removing the checks involving `message_last_write_id_*`. Those checks may seem to be limiting the number of rows in the result set (thus potentially speeding up the subqueries), but in reality, if a message matches the conversation and its ID is larger than the last read ID and the poster is not `user.id` but the other party, then it is an unread message for `user.id`.

So, this is how you could count `unread_user1`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  message AS m
  INNER JOIN conversation AS c
    ON  m.conversation_id = c.id
    AND m.poster_id = c.user2_id
WHERE
  c.user1_id = u.id
  AND m.id > COALESCE(c.message_last_read_id_user1, 0)
```

You could also try replacing the `m.id > COALESCE(c.message_last_read_id_user1, 0)` predicate with a disjunction to see if it can result in a more efficient execution plan for the entire query:

```
  …
  AND (c.message_last_read_id_user1 IS NULL
    OR m.id > c.message_last_read_id_user1)
```

Similarly, this would be the subquery for `unread_user2`:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  message AS m
  INNER JOIN conversation AS c
    ON  m.conversation_id = c.id
    AND m.poster_id = c.user1_id
WHERE
  c.user2_id = u.id
  AND m.id > COALESCE(c.message_last_read_id_user2, 0)
  -- or like this:
  -- AND (c.message_last_read_id_user2 IS NULL
  --   OR m.id > c.message_last_read_id_user2)
```